# How to use lighthouse with specific cookie of login details?

Tags: cookies, lighthouse

I'm trying to run `Lighthouse` on my website from the command line.
When `Chrome` browser opens it comes without any cookies, therefore the desired page isn't loaded and instead I get my login page.
I tried to use `--extra-headers` flag when running lighthouse with a cookie, but I'm not sure this is the right way (and if so, what should be come inside "Cookie" attribute)

Running `Lighthouse` with:

```
lighthouse SITE_URL --output json --output-path ./report.json --extra-headers=./headers.json
```

And the `headers.json` file is:

```
{
  "Cookie": "Username=my_username; Password:my_password;"
}
```

Is that the right way to insert a cookie for loading a website ?
If so, what is the right syntax for custom cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view the right syntax for the cookie, I logged in and copied the Session value for logging in.

```
{
  "Cookie": "mySession=SESSION_HASH;"
}
```